# How to query for active pool stake for an epoch from cardano-db-sync

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I’m attempting to get the active stake value from cardano-db-sync for a pool at a specific epoch so I know how much stake it had for the next snapshot.

I’m currently using the following query

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM epoch_stake 

WHERE epoch_stake.epoch_no = $1 AND pool_id = $2
```

This query seems to work, but my result is quite a bit off when compared to what cardanoscan.io shows as the active stake for the same pool.

Comment: Active stake is an instantaneous stake distribution at the current block (and can change with each new block) whereas the `epoch_stake` table gives the stake distribution for a single epoch.